# Plotting over multiple pages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to write a function that plots a ggplot `facet_wrap` plot over multiple pages. It's just a hack, as this feature seems to be on the ggplot2 feature to-do list. I do some small calculations to find the number of pages I'm going to need, the number of rows of my `data.frame` that I need per page etc. I'm pretty confident this all works.

```
pdf(filename)
for (i in seq(num_pages)){
    slice = seq(((i-1)*num_rows)+1,(i*num_rows))
    slice = slice[!(slice > nrow(df.merged))]
    df.segment=df.merged[slice,]
    p <- ggplot(df.segment, aes(y=mean,x=phenotype))
    p <- p + geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="white",colour="black") 
    p + facet_wrap("ID",scales="free_y",ncol=n_facets,nrow=n_facets)
}
dev.off()
```

My problem is that, by wrapping it all up in a for loop like this, in between the `pdf()` and `dev.off()` functions, is that the for loop doesn't seem to wait for ggplot to do its thing, and blazes through its loop very quickly and outputs an invalid PDF.

If I set `i = 1`, start the `pdf()`, run the above code inside the for loop, then set `i=2`, then run the code, and so on until I get bored (`i=3`) then turn off the device the resulting PDF is brilliant.

Is there a way I can get the for loop to wait for the final line to finish plotting before moving onto the next iteration?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need print() around your last line (p+ ...) to get it to actually print to the device inside the for loop . . .

Comment: wow that completely works. I had no idea that print could be used like  this.

Comment: It's because `p` is an object. The last line of your code modifies the `p` object, but then you want to `print()` it to the device.

Comment: Yup, it's a common obstacle. Sometimes I write a function in ggplot2, and omit `print()` around the final part, hence get no output...

Comment: I think we all make that mistake.  I posted a near identical question a few months ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277166/saving-dotplot-to-pdf-in-r

Comment: Heh... me, too.  One of the pitfalls of the interactive console.

Comment: is print overloaded for objects of class `class(p)`? I feel that I'm close to understanding something here...

Answer (score 6):

Exactly. Page 39 of the ggplot2 book tells us that when you create ggplot2 objects, you can "Render it on screen, with print(). This happens automatically when running interactively, but inside a loop or function, you'll need to print() it yourself".