# R: cairo_pdf output size and plot size

Tags: r, pdf, plot, cairo

When long text is placed along y-axis in `ggplot` and `cairo_pdf` is called without `width` and `height`, it uses `width = 7, height = 7` parameters, so that wide plots can't fit the output PDF.

Is it possible to let `cairo_pdf` decide the size of the PDF for readers to see the entire plot in the produced PDF?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888225/automatically-adjust-r-plot-size-in-a-pdf-output) one can find solution via `ggsave`, but it doesn't fit this case because `ggsave` has problems with non-Latin characters in PDF output.

A code example:

`cairo_pdf`: Well-behaving PDF. The plot doesn't fit the PDF.

```
cairo_pdf("out_cairo.pdf")
df <- data.frame(x = c("Несмотря на то, что доктора лечили его, пускали кровь и давали пить лекарства, он всё-таки выздоровел.", "B"), y = c(15, 20))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar") +
  coord_flip()
dev.off()
```

`pdf`: Text is overlapping.

```
pdf("out_pdf.pdf")
df <- data.frame(x = c("Несмотря на то, что доктора лечили его, пускали кровь и давали пить лекарства, он всё-таки выздоровел.", "B"), y = c(15, 20))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar") +
  coord_flip()
dev.off()
```

Comment: Did you try to save with the `pdf` function?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein `pdf` doesn't notice non-Latin characters either. The pdf looks like overlapping layers of text and graphics.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to provide a short reproducible example.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Sure. Added the code to the post. That shows why `pdf` is not an option and how 7x7 looks like.

Comment: Can't you specify encoding in pdf?

Comment: @Thomas Adobe Reader says "Custom". I tried to specify "CP1251.enc" and "UTF-8" in `pdf()`, but the former didn't help and the latter wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

This makes room for a pathologically wide margin and a plot. If you wnated this to be programmatic you could write a `mycairo` function that accepted a dataframe and used strwidth to find the maximum length of the printed x value.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Несмотря на то, что доктора лечили его, пускали кровь и давали пить лекарства, он всё-таки выздоровел.", "B"), y = c(15, 20))
ylablen <- strwidth(df$x[1])
cairo_pdf("out_cairo.pdf", width= ylablen+5)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar") +
  coord_flip()
dev.off()
```