# ddply and ggplot - generating no plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr

I have a data which is given below:

```
> dput(qq)
structure(list(SIC = c(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50), AVGAT = c(380.251, 391.3885, 
421.72, 431.83, 483.715, 600.0715, 698.5945, 733.814, 721.426, 
706.0265, 698.41, 697.9565, 720.761, 855.5245, 1023.226, 1214.8215, 
1369.7605, 1439.2765, 1602.3845, 1949.69), ADA = c(0.0223312309851002, 
0.00984600086327487, 0.0199212814576842, 0.0562291585405388, 
0.0155376903911516, 0.0195296616004618, 0.00650206622557842, 
0.0295510054117198, 0.0471091745681615, 0.0898164879903691, 0.154998113255882, 
0.0347106350470676, 0.109407241662021, 0.057428893735577, 0.0637457846236655, 
0.0584883505633773, 0.0439293152619417, 0.030699982198924, 0.00900414418496609, 
0.0293862740698763), NLEAD = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("SIC", "AVGAT", "ADA", 
"NLEAD"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I run the following code, the code doesn't plot anything:

```
clusmypath <- file.path("C:", "Users", "Swordfish", "Dropbox", "aaa.pdf");
pdf(file = clusmypath);
library(ggplot2);
ww <- ddply(qq, .(SIC), function(p){ggplot(p,aes(x=AVGAT,y= ADA, color = NLEAD)) + geom_point(shape=1) ;return(p)});
dev.off();
```

However, when I plot the full data :

```
clusmypath <- file.path("C:", "Users", "Swordfish", "Dropbox", "aaa.pdf");
pdf(file = clusmypath);
library(ggplot2);
ggplot(qq, aes(x = AVGAT, y = ADA, color = NLEAD)) + geom_point(shape=1)  
dev.off();
```

I get a plot. How can I make ddply part to work? Thanks.

Comment: `p` not the resulting plot, it is the data you feed `ggplot` with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return(p)` in your script doesn't return a plot. `p` refers to each subset of the data frame `qq`.  In general, to 'return' plots produced by `ggplot` inside functions you need to use `print` (see [FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f)). However, in your particular case, where you want to save plots, you don't need `print`.

**Several PDF files**

If you want one file per level of 'SIC', you may try something like this. `d_ply` is useful when you call a function only for its side effects, like here when we save the output from a plot. Instead of `pdf`/`some-plotting`/`dev.off`, you may use `ggsave`.

```
d_ply(qq, .(SIC), function(p){
  ggplot(p, aes(x = AVGAT, y = ADA, color = NLEAD)) + geom_point(shape = 1)
  ggsave(file = paste0(unique(p$SIC), ".pdf"))
  })
```

**One PDF file with several pages**

If you want one PDF file, with one page per level of 'SIC', you may use `base` function `pdf`, and the `.print = TRUE` argument in `d_ply`.

```
# create a new SIC variable with two levels, for a more realistic test of the function
qq$SIC2 <- rep(c(50, 100), each = 10)

pdf(file = "aaa.pdf")

d_ply(qq, .(SIC2), .print = TRUE, function(p){
ggplot(p, aes(x = AVGAT, y = ADA, color = NLEAD)) + geom_point(shape = 1)
})

dev.off()
```

Comment: But the program is creating multiple files. I want to save only one pdf file with multiple graphs. If I use just one file name it just saves last file. Is there any way I can save multiple plots in one pdf file?

Comment: Is there a way I can control the number of plots per page under the code you have provided? I want to plot 6 graphs per page. How can we use gridExtra to do that?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809488/handle-multiple-plot-with-ggplot-r/16814123#16814123) may be helpful. Good luck!