# ggplot2 and function for several plots with same variables

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I want to plot 10 figures, with the same variable(s), but different actors (I want to have a plot for every actor).

```
actor1 <- subset (actor, actor$Actor=="Actor1")

plot_actor1 <- ggplot(actor1, aes(x = Date, y = Var))+
  geom_point(shape=15)
  ylim(0,30)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=12)+
  geom_hline(yintercept=17)+
  theme_bw()

pdf("actor1", paper='A4r', width=11)
actor1
dev.off()
```

Data ("actor" - excerpt):

```
Actor   Date    Var
Actor1  0101    12
Actor1  0102    14
Actor1  0103    17
Actor1  0104    11
Actor1  0105    9
Actor1  0106    21
Actor2  0101    6
Actor2  0102    17
Actor2  0103    15
Actor2  0104    19
Actor2  0105    25
Actor2  0106    3
```

I could do that manually, but isn't there another solution (with a loop or a function), where I can replace the "actor1" with names of all my actors (from actor1 until actor10)?

Comment: Take a look at `facet_grid()`.

Comment: Yesterday I answered [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048287/ddply-and-ggplot-generating-no-plot/20048855#20048855) about creating and saving several plots, looping over a grouping variable. You may check if you can adapt the answer to your specific needs. I know there are several other nice examples on SO. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should be good just adding

```
+ facet_grid(.~Actor)
```

To the ggplot call.

Comment: No. I do not want one plot with 10 facets, but 10 plots.