# Multiple graphs over multiple pages using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am doing an exploratory analysis of my data and need to plot multiple graphics using ggplot. The amount of graphics is really huge (206 Stations), and I wanted to plot them in 1 column vs. 8 rows per page over the so many pages needed. I am aware of functions like viewport or grid.arrange, but I am not managing to make them work in this case. I have already noticed that layout() nor par(mfrow=c(8,1)) do not work with ggplot, but I send the part of the code where I am stuck bellow. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
pdf('test.pdf', width=21, height=27)
par(mfrow=c(8,1))
for(i in levels(tab$Station))
{

print(ggplot(tab[tab$Station==i], aes(x=Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Tmin), col="blue", size=0.1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=Tmax), col="red", size=0.1) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=as.Date('2010-01-01'), y=45), label=i) +
  ylim(0, 45) + 
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    plot.background = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
    ,panel.border = element_rect(color = 'black')
    ,panel.background = element_blank()

  )
)

}

dev.off()
```

Comment: Hi Jose, would you mind making this a reproducible examples?  That commonly means providing toy data so that we can just grab the code and run it.  Most often, people use the `data()` function to do this.  For example `data(mtcars)` loads that `mtcars` data.frame into memory.

Comment: Did the answer by @baptiste work?

Comment: I know it's an old question - but try using the facet_wrap_paginate function in the ggforce package.  See help here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggforce/ggforce.pdf that's how I solved my similar problem.

Answer (score 12):

```
library(plyr)
library(gridExtra)

p = ggplot(tab, aes(x=Date)) +
       geom_line(aes(y=Tmin), col="blue", size=0.1)

plots = dlply(tab , "Station", `%+%`, e1 = p)
ml = do.call(marrangeGrob, c(plots, list(nrow=8, ncol=1)))
ggsave("multipage.pdf", ml)
```

untested.

Comment: could you explain what you did to create the `plots` object above? What does ``%+%`` do?

Comment: `%+%` overrides the data in a ggplot

Comment: I'm still an r green-belt so need help from a 4th-Dan black-belt such as yourself. Also I'm only just now getting familiar with using `plyr` and `dplyr` instead of the `apply` family. So I'm guessing here, but does this mean you've passed the subsetted `tab` object (subsetted by Station) into the ggplot `p`, using the `%+%` function to override the place the `tab` argument held in the original? If so that's fantastic.

Comment: than you @baptiste. Excuse the follow-up but what does the `e1 =` do in the `dlply` function? When I remove it and just put `p` in its place the `plots` function still works but suddenly calling the `plots` object results in no graphs appearing.

Comment: `%+%` is an infix operator, with two arguments named `e1` and `e2`. It's defined rather awkwardly, with the case of interest here considering `e1` a ggplot, and `e2` a data.frame (or other things, actually). The dlply loop (equiv. lapply) would feed the function with data.frames as first parameter by default, unless one passes explicitly a plot as named first argument (dlply then jumps to the next one).

Comment: So I tried this method and it did not work. I got this error: Error in gList(data = list(wrapvp = list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"  - Does this method still work?

Comment: Recent version is updated Use the following ```marrangeGrob(grobs = plots, nrow=2, ncol=2)``` instead of ```do.call```

Answer (score 1):

You should simplify your plot since once you get the right order with a simple plot you just replace it with your complicated one. `ggplot2` are based on `grid` package so you need to use `gridExtra` to arrange your plots. Then you loop through , for each 8 plots, you store them in a list and you call `grid.arrange` over it, and you repeat this until the end of your plots...

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
pdf('test.pdf', width=21, height=27)
i = 1
plot = list() 
for (n in unique(tab$Station)){
  ### process data for plotting here ####
  plot[[i]] = ggplot(tab[tab$Station==n], aes(x=Date)) +...
  if (i %% 8 == 0) { ## print 8 plots on a page
    print (do.call(grid.arrange,  plot))
    plot = list() # reset plot 
    i = 0 # reset index
  }
  i = i + 1
}
if (length(plot) != 0) { 
  print (do.call(grid.arrange,  plot))
}
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

Faceting might be the way to go. Decide how many faceted mini-plots you want per page, then loop through the required number of times, generating a png or a pdf as you go. So if you have 200 data items and you want 50 per page, in facets of 5 across and 10 down, just loop through 200/50 = 4 iterations. Crude, but should work.

[image: facets]

```
library(ggplot2)

ii <- 7
nn <- 49

mydf <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(as.Date('2013-03-01'),
                       by = 'day', length.out = ii), nn),
                   value = rep(runif(nn, 100, 200)))

mydf$facet.variable <- rep(1:nn, each = ii)

p <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = date, y = value)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ facet.variable, ncol = ii)

print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `mfrow` doesn't work with `ggplot2`. You have to use other methods like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2-in-r) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398568/r-ggplot-plotting-over-multiple-pages) or use the native `plot` function.

Maybe you can use faceting to get the 8 plots onto one page, then the second link to put it into multiple documents...