# Multiple graphs over multiple pages using ggplot and marrangeGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2, plyr, gridextra

Although this might be a duplicate, I would like to know the solution for my question. I tried to run the code from  question [Multiple graphs over multiple pages using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059826/multiple-graphs-over-multiple-pages-using-ggplot) but I don't know how the data is strucured and therefore could not run it.
I want to plot multiple graphs and print them on multiple pages in a pdf. I tried it with mtcars:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
library(gridExtra)

mtcars2 = melt(mtcars, id.vars='mpg')
mtcars2$group[mtcars2$variable  %in% c("cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat")] <- "A"
mtcars2$group[mtcars2$variable  %in% c("wt", "qsec", "vs", "am")] <- "B"
mtcars2$group[mtcars2$variable  %in% c("gear", "cyl")] <- "C"


p = ggplot(mtcars2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(value,mpg, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(value,mpg, colour=variable), method="lm", se=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 60))+
  labs(x = "Percentage cover (%)", y = "Number of individuals (N)")

plots = dlply(mtcars2, "group", `%+%`, e1 = p)
ml = do.call(marrangeGrob, c(plots, list(nrow=2, ncol=2)))
ggsave("multipage.pdf", ml)
```

produces error `Error in (function (grobs, ncol, nrow, ..., top = quote(paste("page",  : argument "grobs" is missing, with no default`. How do I get this script running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *ggplus* package:

```
https://github.com/guiastrennec/ggplus
```

I particularly find it easier than messing with the ArrageGrobs/gridExtra; it automagically puts the facets in several pages for you.

Since you saved your initial plot as **"p"**, your code would then look like:

```
# Plot on multiple pages
facet_multiple(plot = p, 
           facets = 'group', #**** 
           ncol = 2, 
           nrow = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. If I use `pdf("your_path/testforum.pdf", width=18, height=9)
ml = facet_multiple(plot = p, 
           facets = 'variable', #**** 
           ncol = 2, 
           nrow = 2)
ggsave("multipage.pdf", ml)     
dev.off()` then it shows empty plots on the last pdf page, where there are only 2 plots left (instead of 4). Do you know, why this happens?

Comment: Glad to hear it works! Check how many plots you are expecting to see, before anything. Let me know if I can contribute with anything more to make this answer marked as accepted.

Comment: I would like to have a pdf with multiple pages with the graphs plotted in 2 columns and 2 rows, an when there are only 2 graphs left, then plotted only 2 on the last page.

Comment: Is there also a parameter `scales = free`? I have very different ranges of the data...

Answer (score 3):

instead of `do.call()` which was required in a previous version of gridExtra, try `marrangeGrob(grobs = plots, nrow=2, ncol=2)`