# Splitting facet_wraps over multiple .png outputs in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to produce multiple facet plots per group in the data. The problem I am facing is that in my real data sometimes facets per group is over 100 and `ggplot2` is trying to put all facets into the one graph. This is not good for the visuality.

Basically, what I want to achieve is that when the certain number of facet windows is exceeded per page (lets say draw 10 window per page) I would like to continue to plot them in the next graphs per group.

The minimal example to make this covers only plotting facets per group.

```
x <- rnorm(25,0,5)
y <- rnorm(25,5,10)

gr=rep(c(1,2),c(20,5))

set <- c(rep(1:20,1),1:5)

test_data <- data.frame(x,y,set,gr)

utils::View(test_data)
```

For this minimal example set number for gr 1 is 20. But I want to separate it so to say 10 facets per page.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

plot_list=list()

for (i in unique(test_data$gr)){


plot_sets<- ggplot(data = test_data[test_data$gr==i,], aes(y = y, x=x,fill=factor(set))) +


geom_point(alpha = 0.8,size=8,shape=21,col="black",aes(group=set)) +


  facet_wrap(~set)+


  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "top",plot.title=element_text(face="bold",colour ="Blue",size=25),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold",size=24), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold",size=24),
        #axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 22 , colour = "black",angle=0,vjust = 0.0, hjust = 0),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 22 , colour = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(size=22, lineheight=1.0,face="bold"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="#FFFFCC", colour="black", size=0.1),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=20,face="bold"),
        legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=26),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.2, "lines"))+
  labs(fill='set',col="set",x = "x",y="y",title=paste(i,j,"my_Sets",sep="_"))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1,nrow=1,size=5)))  

  plot_list[[i]]=plot_sets

}
```

## Saving the graphs in .png format

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(test_data$gr))) {

  file_name = paste(unique(test_data$gr), "my_sets.png", sep="_")

  png(paste("C:/test","/",file_name[i],sep=""), width =6400, height =4400, pointsize = 16, units = 'px', res = 200)

  grid.draw(plot_list[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
```

I found some relevant posts like

[Multiple graphs over multiple pages using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059826/multiple-graphs-over-multiple-pages-using-ggplot)

[ggplot2: Plots over Multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736655/ggplot2-plots-over-multiple-pages)

but they use .pdf output  and this example is the most relevant one but it works wit .pdf output

@agstudy solution with .pdf output version

```
tab <- data.frame(Date = rep(seq(as.Date('2013-03-01'),
                       by = 'day', length.out = ii), nn),
                   value = rep(runif(nn, 100, 200)))

tab$Station <- rep(1:nn, each = ii)

*library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
pdf('test.pdf', width=21, height=27)
i = 1
plot = list() 
for (n in unique(tab$Station)){
  ### process data for plotting here ####
  plot[[i]] = ggplot(tab[tab$Station==n,], aes(x=Date,y = value)) +

    geom_line() +
    facet_wrap(~ Station, ncol = 5)

  if (i %% 20 == 0) { ## print 8 plots on a page
    print (do.call(grid.arrange,  plot))
    plot = list() # reset plot 
    i = 0 # reset index
  }
  i = i + 1
}

if (length(plot) != 0) { 
  print (do.call(grid.arrange,  plot))
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: any questions regarding to post ?

Comment: Have you tried `pagination` with [`ggforce`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggforce/vignettes/Visual_Guide.html#pagination) yet?

Comment: @Tung I haven't heard about that? Could you suggest how to implement to this code ?

Comment: Maybe look at the documentation, have a go yourself, and then post an answer for us if you manage?

Comment: @dash2 yes, I am on it! But anybody has the solution without using `ggforce` or `ggplus` that is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here is an example that uses `cut()` and `ggsave()`.

Let's say you have 80 sets that you would like to facet wrap.

```
library(tidyverse)

param_n <- 800

data <- data_frame(
  x = rnorm(param_n, 0, 5),
  y = rnorm(param_n, 5, 10),
  group = factor(sample(c(1, 0), param_n, TRUE)),
  set = sample(1:(param_n / 10), param_n, TRUE)
)
```

That's way to many for one plot, so you use `cut()` to split it into ten pages.

```
data_cut <- 
  data %>%
  mutate(page = cut(set, 10))           # split into 10 groups
```

You then just loop over each page, `filter()` out that data, and save a `.png` file with `ggsave()`.

```
for (current_page in levels(data_cut$page)) {

  fig <- 
    data_cut %>%
    filter(page == current_page) %>%
    ggplot(
      aes(y = y, x = x,
          colour = group,
          group = set)) +
    facet_wrap(~ set) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = paste("Sets", current_page)) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")

  ggsave(
    paste0("figures_sets_", current_page, ".png"),
    plot = fig
  )

}
```

[image: Example output]

I simplified your plot make the code more compact.